# Difference between using an Interface and directly passing Activity to implement Callback

Tags: android, android-activity, callback

I have noticed that I can create a callback by using two methods:

1. Receive an interface at the constructor of the class implementing the callback.
2. Receive the activity itself at the constructor of the class implementing the callback.

**First Approach**
For example I could do this:

```
    public MyClass(MyInterface listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

And I could call `myCallBackFunction()` defined in `MyActivity` (which implements `MyInterface`) by writing `listener.myCallBackFunction()`

**Second Approach**
Or I could do this:

```
    public MyClass(MyActivity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}
```

And I could call `myCallBackFunction()` defined in `MyActivity` by writing `activity.myCallBackFunction()`

**My concern:** Is one approach better than the other? And if so, why?

Comment: the first one, as `MyInterface` can be implemented by any class and any class implementing that iface can be passed thru

Answer (score 3):

Usually speaking, you'd better use first approach. The reason is here:

Suppose you have 4 classes, first is `Vehicle`, second is `Bicycle`, third is `Bus` and third is `Subway`. `Bicycle`, `Bus` and `Subway` are subclasses of `Vehicle`. There may be a method call `drive()`, which should have a parameter. Which one do you think best for parameter type? `Bicycle`, `Bus`, `Subway`, or `Vehicle`?

Apparently, passing `Vehicle` is best because you may want to add other kinds of vehicles in the future or you don't want to write nearly same code for different kinds of vehicles in your project. It is same to use Interface rather than specific class.

As a result, passing an interface to a method is always correct and better than passing a specific type of object to it. You can always implement the interface in other classes and they will also be parameter of that method. You don't need to think about actual type of the parameter, which will confuse you and make you think more about specific code for specific type. Instead, only one type, one piece of code macroscopically.

So the conclusion is: using `MyActivity` is good, but using `MyInterface` is better.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can depend on what you're trying to achieve: the first approach may in general be better suited since `MyClass` is not required to know anything about the implementation of that interface method, so it's great for passing different objects (e.g. a RecyclerView Adapter being created with an OnItemClickedListener injected in the constructor can be re-used in different activities/fragments implementing the interface, whilst the adapter doesn't need to change). It helps to prevent coupling.

The second approach leaves one wondering: is `MyClass` tied to the activity lifecycle? It may still hold a reference to the activity after that activity has actually been destroyed by the system, which would leak memory as the Activity object is not garbage-collected. It's a matter of design, and can be seen as code smell, can you not achieve what you wanted within the activity itself, and rely on the lifecycle callbacks onCreate/.../onDestroy?

Answer (score 0):

**Is one approach better than the other? And if so, why?**

Using `Interface` is the best way..

Assume that you are having

1) **Activity** `MyActivity`

2) `class` which extends **Activity** or **View** or **Asynctask** is `Myclass`.

Both `MyActivity` and `Myclass` are Implements `MyInterface`

If you are passing Activity you need to add one more constructor

```
 public MyClass(MyActivity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
 }

 public MyClass(Myclass myclass) {
    this.myclass= myclass;
 }
```

If you are using interface

```
public MyClass(MyInterface listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

that's it.

Comment: You are assuming that I am implementing MyInterface. But if I am going to pass MyActivity, then I wouldn't be implementing MyInterface, right?

Answer (score -1):

In one approach you are creating an instance of Interface and in another an instance of implementing activity. what is best is:

```
Interface interface;

public myClass(Activity acitivity)

{
   interface = (Interface)activity;
}
```

i.e. typecast activity to interface. Now you can callback the overridden functions in Activity.

This way you can now loose information of Activity's functions and just access the overriden functions of interface from the activity.

You can avoid typecasting and create an object of Activity, if you need access to interface callbacks AND the activity's function/variables.

It depends on your needs.